# Movie quotes: Not my diagnosis!

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Batman has just fought off Scarecrow and a group of Batman wannabes]
>
> Batman: Don't let me find you out here again.
>
> Brian: We're trying to help you!
>
> Batman: I don't need help.
>
> Dr. Jonathan Crane: **Not my diagnosis**!
>
> Brian: What gives you the right? What's the difference between you and
> me?
>
> [Batman lowers himself into the Batmobile]
>
> Batman: I'm not wearing hockey pads!
>
> -- The.Dark.Knight 2008

What's meant by **Not my diagnosis** in this context? I don't get it.

Comment: Somehow I got it. The doctor is saying "I disagree with you. My diagnosis is that you (Batman) really need help". Am I right?

Comment: You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, we need to expand Dr Crane's contracted sentence. He's really saying

> "*[That's]* not my diagnosis!"

With this clarification, suddenly we have a subject for the sentence - the subject being Batman's previous sentence. Dr Crane is saying "I don't agree with you" or "I wouldn't diagnose the situation in that way"

Or more explicitly

> "I disagree, you do need help"

Note that Jonathan Crane is a Doctor. While this doesn't actually matter (anyone can use the word diagnosis) it is an attempt at a joke. Superhero comics in particular are full of rubbish jokes like these, which are part of their charm

A doctor looks at a patient and "diagnoses" the illness/problem. In this context, he is "diagnosing" that Batman needs help.

Comment: Dr. Crane's specialty is psychiatry, which means that he specifically diagnoses mental illnesses.  The phrase "you need help" is a common euphemism for "you need psychiatric care".  Or, even more explicitly than above, "You think that you don't need help?  That's not my diagnosis.  You do have a mental illness, and you do require psychiatric treatment."